# Python task I'm having trouble running

Tags: python

I've start a new course at Udemy, its called "Python bootcamp, from zero to hero".
Well, one of the assigment after the basic lectures is to write a guessing game, those are the rules:

The Challenge:

Write a program that picks a random integer from 1 to 100, and has players guess the number. The rules are:

If a player's guess is less than 1 or greater than 100, say "OUT OF BOUNDS"
On a player's first turn, if their guess is
within 10 of the number, return "WARM!"
further than 10 away from the number, return "COLD!"
On all subsequent turns, if a guess is
closer to the number than the previous guess return "WARMER!"
farther from the number than the previous guess, return "COLDER!"
When the player's guess equals the number, tell them they've guessed correctly and how many guesses it took!

Im trying to write this without the guidance, just from the basic tools that I learned. So far. this is my code (still working on it)

```
guess=randint(0,100)

## Guessing game ! 
# In this game, we will pick a random integer from the integers in the segment [0,100]. 
# In each step one should guess the integer that the system chose.
# Once you gussed correctly, you will win the game.

GuessList=[]

Guess=input('Your Guess is: ')
GuessList.append(Guess)

if int(Guess)<0 or int(Guess)>100:
    print('OUT OF BOUNDS')

else:
    if  int(Guess)==int(guess):
        print('Congragulations, you have earned your chicken for friday \n Game is over now.')
    else:
        if 0<int(guess)-int(Guess)<10:
            print('Warm')
        elif 0<int(Guess)-int(guess)<10:
            print('Warm')
        else:
            print('Cold')
        NewGuess=input('Your new guess is: ')
        
        
if int(NewGuess)==int(guess):
     print('Congragulations, you have earned your chicken for friday \n The game is over now')                

while int(NewGuess)!=int(guess):
    if int(NewGuess)<0 or int(NewGuess)>100:
        print('OUT OF BOUNDS')
    else:
        GuessList.append(NewGuess)
        if 0<int(NewGuess)-int(Guess)<int(Guess)-int(guess):
            print('WARMER')
        elif 0<int(NewGuess)-int(Guess)<int(guess)-int(Guess):
            print('WARMER')
        elif 0<int(Guess)-int(NewGuess)<int(guess)-int(Guess):
            print('WARMER')
        elif 0<int(Guess)-int(NewGuess)<int(Guess)-int(guess):
            print('WARMER')
        else:
            print('COLDER')
        NewGuess=input('Your new guess is: ')
```

Im sure that's pretty bad. My problems are:

First, I know that I havent done what was written in the task. My code does not tell the one who guess if he closer to the right number in relation to his privious guess, but rather in relation to the first guess. Dont tell me how to write it in correctly, I'll figure it out once I'll understand the more crucial problem:

As it is written, no matter what Im trying to guess, it never ends the game (as if all the number between 0-100) are incorrect.

also when I run it and the try to run the simple code `guess`, it does nothing (Im working in jupiter notebooks).

But if I do not run this code, and just run `guess=randint(0,100)` and then run `guess` it does show me the number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the problems one by one:

1. You are comparing `NewGuess` to `Guess` (`int(NewGuess)-int(Guess)`) and `Guess` is the first guess
2. I don't see any reason as to why the game doesn't end. The game *should* end as long as you don't input any number out of range. There isn't any print statement when the game ends so maybe that's why you think it doesn't end.
3. Again, `guess` *should* be a number in the interval [1, 100]. Maybe you didn't import `randint` from the `random` module?

I would highly suggest following the course to the letter to learn how to code correctly. Even better, get yourself a book written by a professional with decades of experience on the subject. Udemy courses are ok but they can only get you so far. Also before coding anything, make a scetch of the thing you're trying to code and how it *should* run. Furthermore, before posting on SO do try and debug it yourself, go through every single line and analyse it; make sure you know *exactly* what it does. SO should be your last resort.

Comment: As for problem 2, there is a print statement the the game ends - when int(NewGuess)==int(guess). Also, I did import the randint from random